# Change `gtsummary::tbl_regression` columns

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to reformat the column in [`gtsummary::tbl_regression`](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_regression.html) similar to [`tbl_summary`](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_summary.html) using the `statistic` argument. However, I cannot find the corresponding argument to make this adjustment. Thank you for your help pointing me to the argument!

For example, instead of:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

glm(response ~ age, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image: gtsummary-tbl]

I would like:

| **Characteristic** | **OR (95% CI; p value)** |
| --- | --- |
| Age | 1.02 (1.00,1.04; 0.10) |

Comment: I've also tried `modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{estimate}** ({ci}; {p.value})")` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge columns in gtsummary, but I will say that this feature is not documented for users because it is still being thought out and it is possible that is implementation may change slightly in a future release. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

glm(response ~ age, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    column = estimate, 
    rows = !is.na(estimate),
    cols_merge_pattern = "{estimate} ({ci}; {p.value})",
    label = "**OR (95% CI; p value)**"
  ) %>%
  modify_footnote(estimate ~ "OR = Odds Ratio, CI = Confidence Interval",
                  abbreviation = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to modify the single footnote, e.g., to include CI, so `1 OR = Odds Ratio, CI = Confidence Interval`. I tried both `footnote_abbrev` and `footnote` arguments within `modify_table_styling()` (which adds a footnote to each cell), as well as `modify_footnote` (which makes no visible change). Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: UPdated the post with code to update the abbreviation